# Nodejs : How to connect to multiple redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

How to set up two redis servers(master/slave) with nodejs?
I use [node_redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis), already try `redis://host:port,host2:port2?db=10&password=bar`

```
var connectionString = 'redis://host:port,host2:port2?db=10&password=bar'
var client = redis.createClient(connectionString);
client.set('key','value',function(err,reply){
   console.log(err);  //the db option is added twice and does not match
   console.log(reply);
});
```

Comment: Did you set up replication in the config?

Comment: @DavidMakogon how to set it ?

Comment: You should look up `redis replication` - lots of documentation published. You cannot replicate just via connection string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few months I found out [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) could help cluster jobs with nodejs!

```
var Redis = require('ioredis');

var cluster = new Redis.Cluster([{
  port: 6380,
  host: '127.0.0.1'
}, {
  port: 6381,
  host: '127.0.0.1'
}]);

cluster.set('foo', 'bar');
cluster.get('foo', function (err, res) {
  // res === 'bar'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to configure your Redis servers to run in cluster mode you can use [thunk-redis](https://github.com/thunks/thunk-redis) library. This library supports connecting to Redis [master-slave](https://redis.io/topics/replication) without having a cluster configured or using a sentinel.

You just simply add multiple IP addresses to the client:

```
const client = redis.createClient(['127.0.0.1:6379', '127.0.0.1:6380'], {onlyMaster: false});
```

Also, this is the suggested Node.js library in the [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial)